# GeoServer unable to validate SLD created in QGIS

Tags: qgis, geoserver, error, sld, svg

I'm creating an SLD file using QGIS 3.28.3, but when I try to validate it in GeoServer I get the following error message:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Parsing failed for Filter: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to find function PropertyName

```
<StyledLayerDescriptor xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:se="http://www.opengis.net/se" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="1.1.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld http://schemas.opengis.net/sld/1.1.0/StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd">
  <NamedLayer>
    <se:Name>ZK_Peje</se:Name>
    <UserStyle>
      <se:Name>ZK_Peje</se:Name>
      <se:FeatureTypeStyle>
        <se:Rule>
          <se:Name>0-100</se:Name>
          <se:Description>
            <se:Title>0-100</se:Title>
          </se:Description>
          <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
            <ogc:And>
              <ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThanOrEqualTo>
                <ogc:PropertyName>Popullsia</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>0</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThanOrEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyIsLessThanOrEqualTo>
                <ogc:PropertyName>Popullsia</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>100</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsLessThanOrEqualTo>
            </ogc:And>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <se:PolygonSymbolizer>
            <se:Fill>
              <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#cdff9e</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="fill-opacity">0.8</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Fill>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#232323</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">1</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:PolygonSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
        <se:Rule>
          <se:Name>101-250</se:Name>
          <se:Description>
            <se:Title>101-250</se:Title>
          </se:Description>
          <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
            <ogc:And>
              <ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThanOrEqualTo>
                <ogc:PropertyName>Popullsia</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>101</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThanOrEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyIsLessThanOrEqualTo>
                <ogc:PropertyName>Popullsia</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>250</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsLessThanOrEqualTo>
            </ogc:And>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <se:PolygonSymbolizer>
            <se:Fill>
              <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#b9e68f</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="fill-opacity">0.8</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Fill>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#232323</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">1</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:PolygonSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
        <se:Rule>
          <se:Name>251-500</se:Name>
          <se:Description>
            <se:Title>251-500</se:Title>
          </se:Description>
          <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
            <ogc:And>
              <ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThanOrEqualTo>
                <ogc:PropertyName>Popullsia</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>251</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThanOrEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyIsLessThanOrEqualTo>
                <ogc:PropertyName>Popullsia</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>500</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsLessThanOrEqualTo>
            </ogc:And>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <se:PolygonSymbolizer>
            <se:Fill>
              <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#a4cc7e</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="fill-opacity">0.8</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Fill>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#232323</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">1</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:PolygonSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
        <se:Rule>
          <se:Name>501-1000</se:Name>
          <se:Description>
            <se:Title>501-1000</se:Title>
          </se:Description>
          <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
            <ogc:And>
              <ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThanOrEqualTo>
                <ogc:PropertyName>Popullsia</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>501</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThanOrEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyIsLessThanOrEqualTo>
                <ogc:PropertyName>Popullsia</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>1000</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsLessThanOrEqualTo>
            </ogc:And>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <se:PolygonSymbolizer>
            <se:Fill>
              <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#90b36f</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="fill-opacity">0.8</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Fill>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#232323</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">1</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:PolygonSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
        <se:Rule>
          <se:Name>1001-2500</se:Name>
          <se:Description>
            <se:Title>1001-2500</se:Title>
          </se:Description>
          <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
            <ogc:And>
              <ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThanOrEqualTo>
                <ogc:PropertyName>Popullsia</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>1001</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThanOrEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyIsLessThanOrEqualTo>
                <ogc:PropertyName>Popullsia</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>2500</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsLessThanOrEqualTo>
            </ogc:And>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <se:PolygonSymbolizer>
            <se:Fill>
              <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#7b995f</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="fill-opacity">0.8</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Fill>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#232323</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">1</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:PolygonSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
        <se:Rule>
          <se:Name>2501-5000</se:Name>
          <se:Description>
            <se:Title>2501-5000</se:Title>
          </se:Description>
          <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
            <ogc:And>
              <ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThanOrEqualTo>
                <ogc:PropertyName>Popullsia</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>2501</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThanOrEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyIsLessThanOrEqualTo>
                <ogc:PropertyName>Popullsia</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>5000</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsLessThanOrEqualTo>
            </ogc:And>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <se:PolygonSymbolizer>
            <se:Fill>
              <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#67804f</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="fill-opacity">0.8</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Fill>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#232323</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">1</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:PolygonSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
        <se:Rule>
          <se:Name>5001-50000</se:Name>
          <se:Description>
            <se:Title>5001-50000</se:Title>
          </se:Description>
          <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
            <ogc:And>
              <ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThanOrEqualTo>
                <ogc:PropertyName>Popullsia</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>5001</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThanOrEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyIsLessThanOrEqualTo>
                <ogc:PropertyName>Popullsia</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>50000</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsLessThanOrEqualTo>
            </ogc:And>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <se:PolygonSymbolizer>
            <se:Fill>
              <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#67804f</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="fill-opacity">0.8</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Fill>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#232323</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">1</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:PolygonSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
        <se:Rule>
          <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
            <ogc:PropertyName>Emri</ogc:PropertyName>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <se:MaxScaleDenominator>99531</se:MaxScaleDenominator>
          <se:TextSymbolizer>
            <se:Label>
              <ogc:PropertyName>Emri</ogc:PropertyName>
            </se:Label>
            <se:Font>
              <se:SvgParameter name="font-family">Open Sans</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="font-size">13</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Font>
            <se:LabelPlacement>
              <se:PointPlacement>
                <se:AnchorPoint>
                  <se:AnchorPointX>0</se:AnchorPointX>
                  <se:AnchorPointY>0.5</se:AnchorPointY>
                </se:AnchorPoint>
              </se:PointPlacement>
            </se:LabelPlacement>
            <se:Fill>
              <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#323232</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Fill>
            <se:VendorOption name="maxDisplacement">1</se:VendorOption>
          </se:TextSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
      </se:FeatureTypeStyle>
    </UserStyle>
  </NamedLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

Comment: is the SLD valid against any SLD schema ~ http://schemas.opengis.net/sld/

Comment: Can you add your SLD to the question

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The final filter is broken:

```
      <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
        <ogc:PropertyName>Emri</ogc:PropertyName>
      </ogc:Filter>
```

You'll need to work out what it should be and fix or delete it.

You should then raise a [bug with the QGis team](https://qgis.org/en/site/getinvolved/development/bugreporting.html) that they are generating invalid SLD on output and [one with the GeoServer team](https://osgeo-org.atlassian.net/jira/software/c/projects/GEOS/issues) as it shouldn't throw an exception rather than giving you a meaningful error message.